# Why is a mattress more comfortable than a solid ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

The main question is: what's the physics behind how mattress is way more comfy than a flat solid ground?
I've observed that since in both cases the weight of the mass on a mattress and on the ground get balanced by the same amount of normal force, so how does the cushion makes a difference?

Comment: A mattress adapts to the shape of your body, reducing pressure since the weight is better distributed.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it

Comment: Depends on the mattress and how bad my back is feeling at the time. Sometimes a hard flat surface feels better.